# Large File Processing - Resume from the point of failure

Tags: java, apache-camel

We have to process large CSV files. We use Apache Camel for reading the files from an SFTP location (But we are open to Java based solutions if there are better approaches).

One of the requirement is to resume the processing from the point of failure. That is, if there is an exception happened while processing line number 1000, we should start processing from line 1000 rather than from the beginning. We should not process the record twice as well.

We are using Apache ActiveMQ to save the records in the queues and for managing the pipeline. But initial loading of the file from the location can also cause failures.

To track the state, we are using a database which will get updated at every step using Apache Camel.

We are open to ideas and suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use insert/updates otherwise known as upserts/merge and threads. I have processed 260GB csv files into a MYSQL database in roughly 4 minutes. Dont over engineer.

Comment: Wow! That's impressive. Can you let me know few mire details please? The kind of processing and what solution did you use? If you add it in the Answer section, I cam accept tha answer and can give points. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, [Camel File component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html) cannot resume from the point of failure.

It depends on your configuration (see `moveFailed` option) if a failed file is moved away or reprocessed on the next attempt (but from the beginning).

To read a CSV file, you need to [split](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html) the single lines. Because your files are big, you should use the `streaming` option of the Splitter. Otherwise the whole file is read before splitting!

To decrease the probability of failures and reprocessing of the whole file, you can simply send every single CSV line to ActiveMQ (without parsing it). The simpler the splitter, the lower the probability that you need to reprocess the whole file because of problems in a single record.

The decoupled consumer of the queue can parse and process the CSV records without affecting the file import. Like this, you can handle errors for every single record.

If you nevertheless have file import failures, the file is reprocessed from the beginning. Therefore you should [design you processing pipeline idempotent](https://www.cloudcomputingpatterns.org/idempotent_processor/). For example check for an existing record and if there is already one, update it instead of just inserting every record.

In a messaging environment you have to deal with [at-least-once delivery semantics](https://www.cloudcomputingpatterns.org/at_least_once_delivery/). The only solution is to have idempotent components. Even if Camel would try to resume at the point of failure, it could not guarantee that every record is read only once.

Comment: Thanks Burki, that makes sense. Camel itself has an idempotent EIP which I guess we can use.